# How do you disable and remove the Windows Defender service permanently - kills battery life and performance running?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I am running the latest updates of Windows, and I want to remove all anti-virus based protection on my laptop for battery savings.

I've tried going into PC Settings and Windows Defender, but it keeps enabling itself like a spying virus that owns my machine...

I've tried this too:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender]
"DisableAntiSpyware"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection]
"DisableRealtimeMonitoring"=dword:00000001
```

Still it comes back on after a reboot.

I can't disable the service either.

Comment: For which windows version are you attempting to do this on?

Comment: Windows 10. I was sure I had windows 10 written in the title or post.

Comment: @FrankThornton what version of Windows 10 (Version 1511, Version 1607, ect). Have you replaced Windows Defender with something, if you did, the Windows defender shouldn't be running unless you enable that feature (version 1607 only)

Comment: This 1511. I've not replaced it with anything.

Comment: This PC connected to a domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

### Three options mentioned on the winaero.com site:

http://winaero.com/blog/disable-or-enable-windows-defender-in-windows-10/

1. Use Winaero
2. Temporarily disable it as you have done before (though most would have thought this was temporary).
3. Via a Group Policy

### A bit more hacker'ish solutions, except the same Group Policy method:

http://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/25/how-to-disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/

1. Group Policy
2. Modify the Registry (also I would think this would work as you try and mentioned)
3. Disable and adding a Task Scheduler
4. A utility program called 'NoDefender' <== I have not tried this

Here is my UPDATE & SECURITY settings page after using the Winareo download (which I did [scan](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/5bac45fbc0a468dac2c18efbcdcb94656bed69d37a83111ad64418075cebe039/analysis/) using https://www.virustotal.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ghacks' second method here worked for me, Windows Defender has been completely disabled for months: http://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/25/how-to-disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/

> **Disabling Windows Defender using the Windows Registry**
>
> You may disable Windows Defender in the Windows Registry as well.
>   Basically, it is the same setting that gets written to it when you
>   disable the application in the Group Policy Editor.
>
> ```
> Tap on the Windows-key to open the Start Menu.
> Type regedit.exe and hit enter.
> Confirm the UAC prompt to continue.
> Navigate to the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender
> If you see the preference DisableAntiSpyware on the right double-click on it and set it to 1 to disable Windows Defender.
> If the preference does not exist, right-click on Windows Defender and select New > Dword (32-bit) Value, and name it DisableAntiSpyware.
> ```
>
> To restore Windows Defender at a later point in time, delete the key
>   or set its value to 0.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to remove the stupid windows defender icon that is everywhere after updating to the latest version of 10

Comment: @FrankThornton: You can remove the icon with ShellExView: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html
Please note that you have to restart Windows Explorer after doing so.